# Restart a Task Scheduler (@Schedule(...)) without restarting the server/wildfly

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I have a task scheduler that runs every 10mins. I noticed that sometimes it stops running, and I need to restart Wildfly or the server for it to kick back up.

Is there a way I can restart the scheduler without restarting the server or Wildfly?
The project is deployed to Wildfly on EC2.

Comment: Assuming your scheduler is inside an autostartup singleton session bean, I think you could restart the bean using the web admin (or via JBoss CLI)

Comment: I would first try to determine why it needs to be restarted.

Comment: Another option would be to externalize the scheduling using Amazon EventBridge: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html